# Values are not inserting in MySQL form from php form even after successful submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am new to PHP and MySQL.
I created a php form to save some data to the databse table.
After submitting the form, it gives

> "1 recorded added"

as specified in the php insert string.
But after opening the table in phpmyadmin, it shows a new row added but no data in it..

The php form is:

```
<h2>Register Yourself</h2>
            <form method="post" action="get-member.php">
                <div>
                    <span><p>First Name:</p></span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Last Name:</span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Father's Name: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="FatherName"></span>
                </div>
                <div>       
                    <span>Mother's Name: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="MotherName"></span>
                </div>
                <div>           
                    <span>Date of Birth: </span>
                    <span><input type="date" class="form-control" id="DOB"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Address: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address"></span>
                </div>
                <div>       
                    <span>City: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="City"></span>
                </div>
                <div>   
                    <span>District: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="District"></span>
                </div>
                <div>       
                    <span>Postal Code: </span>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="PostalCode"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Personal Mobile #:</span>
                    <span><input type="number" class="form-control" id="Pmobile"></span>
                </div>
                <div>   
                    <span>Father's Contact #:</span>
                    <span><input type="number" class="form-control" id="Fmobile"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Mother's Contct #:</span>
                    <span><input type="number" class="form-control" id="Mmobile"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Home contact #:</span>
                    <span><input type="number" class="form-control" id="Hmobile"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input type="submit" value="Register"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and the get-member.php file is:

```
<?php


//stablising connection
include("../database/connection.php"); 

//escape variables for security
$FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['FirstName']);
$LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['LastName']);
$FatherName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['FatherName']);
$MotherName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['MotherName']);
$DOB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DOB']);
$Address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Address']);
$City = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['City']);
$District = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['District']);
$PostalCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['PostalCode']);
$Pmobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Pmobile']);
$Fmobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Fmobile']);
$Mmobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Mmobile']);
$Hmobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Hmobile']);




$sql="INSERT INTO RUPmembers (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, MotherName, DOB, Address, City, District, PostalCode, Pmobile, Fmobile, Mmobile, Hmobile)

VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$FatherName','$MotherName','$DOB','$Address','$City','$District','$PostalCode','$Pmobile','$Fmobile','$Mmobile','$Hmobile')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die ('Error:' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 Record addedd";




//closing connection
include("../database/close-connection.php");

?>
```

The phpmyadmin table after inserting 3 data(s):

[*sorry it is requesting to gain 10 repo to be able to add image, but here is the link of the screenshot http://oi60.tinypic.com/n6rtyu.jpg* ]

Comment: This code is susceptible to sql-injection. This is very dangerous as attackers can maniupulate your database. Also your string concatenation is not working. PHP string concatenation would look something like `VALUES ('".$FirstName."' `

Comment: Please note, that such code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You should sanitize your inputs before working with database, or use parametrized parameters:
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO RUPmembers (FirstName) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $FirstName);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: Dear Pankrates and @mikiqex the above questing has been updates as per your suggestion to sql injection susceptibility. Thnks to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName">

to

> input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName">

This should slove your problem however do not insert unmanipulated info from users into your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are using id="FirstName"

You need to have the property `name` set for each field. For example:

```
name="FirstName"
```

To debug this, you should take a look at your `$_POST` vars using `var_dump($_POST)` to show what is being passed on from the form.

Note:  Queries should be protected from any data received from the user to prevent sql injection. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn how to avoid this.

Comment: although true, this is not the least of this problems. His string concatenation is incorrect and he is massively vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Thanks @mseifert, actualy i'm newbie to php. You have solved my problem within seconds. Thanks again, I had lost my last night solving this.

Comment: you are right @Pankrates, i understand the same, actualy the escape variable string was like this, $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['FirstName']); but i removed the same in shake to solve the problem bt nothing special happend, I will add it back again. Thanks to you too

Comment: Glad to help. It is often the simplest of things when starting out. My answer stayed strictly to what you were asking and what I believed was holding you up. However, the comment from @Pankrates regarding sql injection is something you should look into. Queries should be protected from Any data received from the user to prevent sql injection. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn how to avoid this.

Comment: @mseifert the question has been updated with regarding sql injection, this syntax I got from www.w3schools.com the official tutorial site of w3.org

Answer (score 0):

To catch data from the html form by php,the name should be given inside the $_post[''] method not the id.
use `name="FirstName"
    name="LastName"
    name="DOB"`
   etc..

it will solve the problem..